# Jquery не видит функцию

Tags: jquery

Jquery не видит функцию `msg_send`, вот код:

```
<img src="/1.png" onclick="sticker('/1.png');" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
function sticker(sticker){
msg_send(sticker);
}

$(function() {
function msg_send(sticker){
// тут ajax
}
});
</script>
```

Понимаю так, что вторая функция внутри другой и первая её не видит, если первую вставить вместе со второй, то есть после `$(function() {`, то при клике не видит первую функцию - `sticker`

Comment: Все логично. Это называется область видимости, мой друг) Вы закрыли `msg_send` внутри другой функции. Конечно же никто не может из вне постучаться и взять то, что лежит в функции

Comment: @АлексейШиманский решение бы.

Comment: в теории `$(function()` это короткая запись `$(document).ready(function()`. А функции должны быть объявлены заранее. Зачем помещать туда объявление функции вообще, можете объяснить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция msg_send() доступна только внутри анонимной функции для $(document).ready
Их нужно или обе выносить за пределы или обе внести.

Comment: Может, есть что-то типа global?

Comment: По возможности стоит избегать использования global

Comment: @Rufex а какой смысл запирать функцию, но использовать глобал? Срячу-ка я все свои деньги в сейф, закрою на кодовый замок, а комбинацию, которая подходит напишу на листочке и оставлю пожалуй на столе. Да. Идеально)

Comment: @Rufex вам видимо кое-что другое нужно. http://coders.ask-ru.net/javascript-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/    смотрите сразу `Yahoo JavaScript Module Pattern` .... если не понравится покрутите в начало к `Локальная область видимости`

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
function msg_send(sticker){
  // тут ajax
}
$(function() {
  ...
});
```